# Rails 3.0 - best practices: multiple subtypes of a model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

So this is probably a fairly easy question to answer but here goes anyway.

I want to have this view, say media_objects/ that shows a list of media objects. Easy enough, right? However, I want the list of media objects to be a collection of things that are subtypes of MediaObject, CDMediaObject, DVDMediaObject, for example. Each of these subtypes needs to be represented with a db table for specific set of metadata that is not entirely common across the subtypes.

My first pass at this was to create a model for each of the subtypes, alter the MediaObject to be smart enough to join into those tables on it's conceptual 'all' behavior. This seems straightforward enough but I end up doing a lot of little things that feel not so rails-O-rific so I wanted to ask for advice here.

I don't have any concrete code for this example yet, obviously, but if you have questions I'll gladly edit this question to provide that information...

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a model for each sub-type is the way to go, but what you're talking about is multiple-table inheritance. Rails assumes single-table inheritance and provides really easy support for setting it up. Add a `type` column to your `media_objects` table, and add all the columns for each of the specific types of MediaObject to the table. Then make each of your models a sub-class of `MediaObject`:

```
class MediaObject < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class CDMediaObject < MediaObject

end
```

Rails will handle pulling the records out and instantiating the correct subclass, so that when you `MediaObject.find(:all)` the results will contain a mixture of instances of the various subclasses of `MediaObject`.

Note this doesn't meet your requirement:

> Each of these subtypes needs to be represented with a db table for specific set of metadata that is not entirely common across the subtypes.

Rails is all about convention-over-configuration, and it will make your life very easy if you write your application to it's strengths rather than expecting Rails to adapt to your requirements. Yes, STI will waste space leaving some columns unpopulated for every record. Should you care? Probably not; database storage is cheap, and extra columns won't affect lookup performance if your important columns have indexes on them.

That said, you can setup [something very close](http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/) to multiple-table inheritance, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: excellent! I was suspicious that perhaps I was trying to take Ruby off the rails. The sparse metadata approach offended my sensibilities, but I've been finding a lot of my pre-existing "sensibilities" are being called into question in RoR. I'm learning and growing :)

Comment: Rails is opinionated software. I also had a lot of misgivings about their assumed defaults, especially in regards to things like foreign key constraints. But, there comes a time when you have to decide to be productive and set aside your personal bias to get things done :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is pretty old but just putting down my thoughts, if somebody lands up here.

In case the DB is postgres, I would suggest use STI along hstore column for storing attributes not common across different objects. This will avoid wasting space in DB yet the attributes can be accessed for different operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it depends on your data: For example, if the differences between the specific media objects do not have to be searchable, you could use a single db table with a TEXT column, say "additional_attributes". With rails, you could then serialize arbitrary data into that column.

If you can't go with that, you could have a general table "media_objects" which "has one :dataset". Within the dataset, you could then store the specifics between CDMediaObject, DVDMediaObject, etc.

A completely different approach would be to go with MongoDB (instead of MySQL) which is a document store. Each document can have a completely different form. The entire document tree is also searchable.